# Unlock iPhone via accessibility button press rather than "Slide to Unlock"?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, accessibility, unlock

I have an old iPhone with a shattered screen. I use it as a dedicated music player.

I can comfortably tap buttons on the screen. But sliding my finger across the screen causes irritation due to the cracked glass. I'm not really using multitouch on this device, so this is mostly fine. I can tap the buttons I need to, and scroll very carefully.

The only time when this is a problem is unlocking the phone. The phone wants me to "slide to unlock" — over the dangerous broken glass.

---

Is there a way to imitate a "slide to unlock" without actually sliding?

Using only on-screen buttons or hardware buttons to bring up the passcode entry.

Is there an Accessibility setting alternative to "slide to unlock"? In addition to broken-glass or broken-touch-sensor scenarios, an AssistiveTouch option might also be useful for people who have difficulties touching the screen accurately.

Using TouchID possibly solves this. But is there a solution for iPhones without TouchID enabled or without a Home button?

Comment: you may want to try an iPhone screen protector. Everything would still work and it will keep your fingers free from glass shards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded the iPhone to iOS 12.4.8.

Now, when I press the Home button on the lock screen, the Passcode entry screen comes up.

If I remove the device's Passcode, clicking the Home button automatically fully unlocks the phone.

This did *not* work in the previous version of iOS the phone was using earlier today. So it was added sometime in the iOS 10, 11, or 12 timeframe.